# iptables proxy local service to external interface

Tags: iptables

I'm running a local service bound to `localhost:1234` only. Can I write a iptables rule to accept a connection on port `1234` on `eth0` (my public interface) and proxy it to `lo` (my loopback). I cannot alter the running service to bind to a different interface.

The service may not be available all the time. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

A rule like this should work:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d <your destination network> --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1234
```

But there is one additional change you need to make before this:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ethN.route_localnet=1
```

... replacing ethN with the nic your IP network resides on.

By default this value is 0, which instructs the kernel to not route external traffic destined to 127.0.0.0/8. This rule is for security as such traffic is mostly unwanted.